# Creating bins dynamically in Tableu

Tags: histogram, tableau-api, bins

I've got 50+ measures and I want to create histogram with binned data and switching displayed measures dynamically. I know how create bins manually but is there any possibility to create bins dynamically?

Comment: anything that you have tried so far? can you show us your code?

Comment: Nope, I need an idea or information if it is possible or not?

Comment: well, everything is possible, just know what we are not here to write code from scratch for anyone, we're here to help with problems, bugs, etc. this asking us to find information for you that you could (I'm guessing) find rather quickly by yourself.

Comment: I searched half of Internet and I did not find any information about it. I've got only example file with prepared measures so I've got nothing what I can show.

Comment: First question, do all 50 measures vary across the same range? If so, then your bin range and sizes would be common for all. If not, say if some values are percentages, others are all positive, others vary between -10M to +10M, then your bins will have to adapt accordingly.